# Does signal "auto-block" (when execution enters handler function) prevents another such signal from being delivered to another thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

Signal mask is thread-specific, which means blocking a signal doesn't prevent it from being delivered to another thread where this signal isn't blocked. When execution enters into a handler function (assuming no `SA_NODEFER`) "current" signal becomes blocked.

Does it mean it will be blocked for all threads in current process or it is possible for next such signal to be delivered to another thread (while it is still being handled in first thread)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading `man sigaction`:

> `sa_mask` specifies a mask of signals which should be blocked (i.e., added to the signal mask **of the thread in which the signal handler is invoked**) during execution of the signal handler. In addition, the signal which triggered the handler will be blocked, unless the `SA_NODEFER` flag is used.

This sounds like the masking of the currently handled signal only affects the handling thread, so other threads may handle further signals.

I think it is typical for a multithreaded system to block *all* signals for all threads except one (or several) dedicated signal handling threads (e.g. one that is polling on a signalfd). That way you never have to worry about signals landing on some unpredictable thread.

Comment: My app links dynamic lib that creates threads on "construct static variables" stage -- there is no good way to set signal mask before that. So now I am trying to deal with this by installing handlers and queuing incoming signals into home-grown structures, which just got even more complicated than I thought it will be... :-(

Comment: @C.M.: Any library code that "transparently" creates threads, e.g. from constructors, should create them with all signals blocked, so that the application need not be aware of the thread's existence. To do this, block all signals before calling `pthread_create` so that the new thread inherits the fully-blocked signal mask and unblock them after `pthread_create` returns. Just blocking in the thread start function is not sufficient; there's a race window where signals are initially unblocked.

Comment: @R I agree, but that library isn't under my control.

Comment: Then you need a high-priority ctor that saves the original signal mask and blocks all signals. Then main can restore the original.

Comment: @R Can't be done if threads are created from constructors of shared library -- these get executed before those in main binary. I ended up rewriting logic in that app so that it doesn't require all threads to block certain signal.